# Aggregate n minutes, n hours and n days into hourly timeframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a **date-indexed, one-minute timeframe** dataset containing `open`, `close`, `high`, `low` and `volume` columns.

1. I want to aggregate last 240 *x* minute, 240 *x* hourly and 240 *x* daily `close` values.
2. Resample the dataframe into 1h hour and aggregated lists above as columns.

So the structure would be literally like this:

```
                 open high low close close240m close240h close240d
2020-01-10 10:00  100  101  99   101   [.....]   [.....]   [.....]
2020-01-10 11:00  101  102  100  101   [.....]   [.....]   [.....]
```

I know a few basic tricks in pandas for example resampling into hourly, or aggregating by 60 mins:

```
ohlc = {    'open': 'first',    'high': 'max',    'low': 'min',    'close': 'last',    'volume': 'sum'}

df.resample('1h').apply(ohlc)

df[['close']].resample('60min').agg(list)
```

But the problem is a bit different since I need last 240 mins for every hour.

What tricks could we use to achieve the above format without making too much mess?

Answer (score 0):

Done the first part.

```
ohlc = {'open': 'first',  'high': 'max',  'low': 'min',  'close': 'last',  'volume': 'sum'}

new_index = pd.date_range(df.index.min(),df.index.max(),freq='1min')
df = df.reindex(new_index)

df.ffill(inplace=True)
df.bfill(inplace=True)

mins = df[['close']].resample('60min').agg(list)
df = df.resample('1h').apply(ohlc)

mins[1:] = mins.shift(1)[1:] + mins[1:]
mins[3:] = mins.shift(2)[3:] + mins[3:]
mins.iloc[2] = mins.iloc[0] + mins.iloc[2]

for i in [0,1,2,3,mins.index.get_loc(mins.index.max())]:
    length = 240 - len(mins.iloc[i].close)
    fill_val = mins.iloc[i].close[0]
    mins.iloc[i].close = [fill_val] * length + mins.iloc[i].close

df['close240m'] = mins
```

Starting with re-indexing to cover missing candle, and filling NA is crucial so that every column has exactly 240 *valid* values, so that we can transfer them to numpy later.

What I did with minute aggregation is quite tricky. 1st step combines `n` and `n-1` rows, then `n` and `n-2` rows, if you scratch your head hard enough you'll get 4 rows by 60 columns stacked together.

Finally looping through initial and ending rows to once again fill the missing values by repeating.

Part 2: settings the hour lists

```
def extend(window):
    lst = window.to_list()
    return [lst[0]]*(240-len(lst)) + lst 

df['close240h'] = [extend(window) for window in df.close.rolling(window=240)]
```